# How can I check to see if a 4-digit number has a duplicate digit or not?

Tags: python, random, numbers

I am currently coding an Aces Jumble Zilch game. In this game, the computer is supposed to generate a 4-digit number with no duplicate digits, and the user needs to figure out what that number is. My question is, "How do I check to see if the random number has a duplicate digit in it? For example, 4444 has duplicate digits but 4321 doesn't.

Comment: Hi Brittney and welcome to stackoverflow. You’ll find that people here are particular about how questions are asked. You should always post what you have tried so far.

Comment: A better way would be to create your list `[1,2,3,4]` and then use `random.shuffle` to rearrange them.  There are only 24 such numbers, so generating a random number below 10,000 and checking it would be horribly wasteful.

Answer (score 0):

Probably best thing to do is to [draw 4 numbers without replacing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample) from the range of 0 to 9 included.

Then add them up in a convenient matter to get a number in the thousands range:

```
from random import sample 

num1 = int(''.join(sample("0123456789", k=4))))

num2 = sum(10**k*v for k,v in enumerate(sample(range(10), k=4)))
```

both would solve this.

- `sample` is the "draw without replacing" - see [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample)
- summing up can be done in strings with a simple [str.join](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) (and then convert to int) -> see `num1`
- or by [enumerating](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) the resulting list of integers and multiplying each digit with 1000, 100, 10, 1 before summing -> see `num2`

---

A `random.shuffle()` would be also possible but needs more lines of code as shuffling is done in-place and returns `None`:

```
from random import shuffle
data = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
shuffle(data) 
n = sum(10**k*v for k,v in enumerate(data[:4]))
```

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is just to check whether the four digits are unique, you can accomplish that with a simple function:

```python
def uniq4(num):
    return len(set(list(str(num)))) == 4
```

This converts the number to a string, then to a list of the individual characters, puts them in a set (which requires uniqueness), then checks to see if the set contains 4 values.
You could make this more general by removing the hard-wired value of 4 and passing the target number of digits as an argument, with a suitable check that it can't be bigger than 10 (or less than 1).

As others have pointed out, it may be a better idea to generate the values to guarantee uniqueness.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the data type of Python to help you in a very simple way.

1. You transform your number into a **string**
2. You make a **set** with each character of you string *(sets do not allow duplicate values)*
3. You check if the **length** of your set is 4, if True, you have 4 distinct numbers! Congrats!

You might be confused, but as many things on python, it's very simple. Take a look

```
import random
n = random.randint(1000,9999)
print(n)
if len(set(str(n))) == 4:
    print(True)
else:
    print(False)
```

If you want to make sure that your code always bring a number with no duplicates, you can right a `def` like this.

```
import random
def number_without_duplicates():
    n = random.randint(1000,9999)
    while len(set(str(n))) != 4:
        n = random.randint(1000,9999)
    return(n)

# to try it
for n in range(10):
    print(number_without_duplicates())
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you want to see if a digit is repeating in a 4-digit integer.

This is my naive solution to this problem.
I would create an `str` object out of the `int`, `list` it then `set` it.
Finally compare the `len` of the `set` to the `len` of the `list`.
Either they have the same length, or there's some digit that is repeating.

```py
def distinct_digits(number):

    digits_string = str(number)
    digits_list = list(digits_string)   #You can't list() an int
    digits_set = set(digits_list)  #This datatype gets rid of duplicates

    return digit_set == digit_list #Think bool() the equality
```

The above function returns `True` if all digits are distinct, and `False` otherwise.

Now, if you wish to find out what digit is repeating. I can think of this naive implementation :

```
def find_repeating_digit(number):

    digits_string = str(number)
    digits_list = list(digits_string)
    
    buffer_list = [] #First digit will go here, afterwards the comparison begins
    duplicates_list = [] #If there's any duplicate digit, it will go here

    for digit in digits_list:
       if digit in buffer_list: #Is digit already in buffer list?
           duplicates_list.append(digit) #Yes, so off to duplicates_list with it
       else: #Otherwise keep on appending digits to the buffer
           buffer_list.append(digit)

    return duplicates_list
```

The above function returns a `list` of duplicates. If there aren't any, then it would be an empty list.

I hope the code isn't too verbose for you. My intent is to be as clear as possible and remain faithful to three of the Zen of Python's verses.

Also, feel free to play around with those two functions, make their returned values of other datatypes (e.g Convert the duplicate back to int, control flow the output, etc, your RAM's the limit).